# instanceof not working as expected between typescript / angular projects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble using instanceof in a angular library where the types should be the same but the instanceof is giving me false.

Below is an example of my logic.

Library Project

```
// dog.ts
export class Dog {
     name: string;
     hungry: boolean;
}

// dogfeeder.ts - static helper class
import {Dog} from './dog.ts';
export class DogFeeder {
     static isDogHungry(dog: Dog): boolean {
          const isDog = dog instanceof Dog; // this is returns false 
          if (!isDog) {
                 // not a dog instance
          }
          return dog.hungry;
     }
}
```

Main Project

```
// mycomponent.ts
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {

     dog: Dog = new Dog();     

     ngOnInit() {
         this.checkOnDog(this.dog);
     }     

     checkOnDog(dog: Dog) {
          const isDog = dog instanceof Dog; // this will return true as expected

          // below when using the static class from my library, the dog parameter isn't returning true 
          // when using the instanceof operator 
          if(DogFeeder.isDogHungry(dog)) {
              // todo:
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo, should be: `if(DogFeeder.isDogHungry(this.dog))` ?

Comment: You have two `dog`s in you're code. You're passing the parameter in the second case, not the class property, is that expected?

Comment: The parameter should still be the class instance but I will adjust my example to clarify.

Comment: There must be something missing in your code, if you check my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/n9zbbv?file=index.html) you can see in the console that it works. Could it be that you have two classes named `Dog` and you are importing different ones?

Comment: The thing with your stackblitz is that it's all in the same file.

Comment: that's irrelevant. even in separate files it works

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, I finally found the issue.  My component file was importing the Dog class with the wrong path.  Vs code did an autocomplete import statement from my library public api file which wasn't the correct path.